# ajax returns true, but == returns false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form and I send it to `php` to insert into `mysql` db by `ajax`. 
everything went good, and `php` return the `"true"` value, but in `ajax` it shows `false` message.

here you can look at the `php` code:-

```
if(isset($result)){
    $value =  array('msg' => 'true' );
} else {
    $value =  array('msg' => 'false' );
}
echo json_encode($value);
```

and this is the `ajax` code:-

```
success: function(value){
    if (value.msg == 'true') { 
        alert("Saved");
    }else{
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

and from console:

```
//value = "↵{"msg":"true"}
```

P.S. I don't know what is the ENTER sign "↵" do in the returned value, but I think it shouldn't affect, right?

Comment: Please share your php+jQuery code fully to address your problem correctly

Comment: when I tried dataType: 'jsonp', neither true message nor false message appears, but data saved correctly

Comment: it's `json` not `jsonp`

Comment: Try : `console.log(typeof(value.msg));`

Comment: oops, yes it worked great, thanks a lot, clearly I was so dummy to type it as [tag:jsonp]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add:-

```
dataType:"json",
```

In your Ajax and it will work.

One more solution is `$.parseJSON` (if you are not using `dataType:"json"`):-

```
success: function(value){
  var json = $.parseJSON(value);
   if (json.msg == 'true') { 
        alert("Saved");
    }else{
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are getting `true` as boolean not as string

Try like this

```
if (value.msg == true) { 
    alert("Saved");
}else{
    alert("Something went wrong.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value you get back is a plain string. Try converting to json:

```
success: function (value) {
    value = JSON.parse(value);
    if(value.msg ==='true') {
         /* your logic here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert json string with parse as below.

```
success: function(value){
var json = $.parseJSON(value);
    if (json.msg == 'true') { 
        alert("Saved");
    }else{
        alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

Please refer this link for more information http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

first check that there is no extra enter before open php tag or after close php tag then add this line to your request:

```
dataType:"json"
```